# Rebasing with Git

Tags: git, rebase, git-rebase, git-pull

I've looked at a ton of articles about how to rebase with Git and it makes sense...or at least I think it does. However, I'm struggling with the following...

For this scenario we have the following branches:

- master (local)
- origin/master
- jheigs (local)
- origin/jheigs

Ok, so now let's say that origin/master is ahead by 1 commit. So, I was told from articles and the dev team I am working on is to do the following on the jheigs branch:

```
$ git add ...
$ git commit ...
$ git status (ensure everything is up-to-date locally)
$ git pull (again, check and ensure that everything is ready to go)
$ git pull --rebase origin master
$ git push (defaulting to origin/jheigs)
```

1. When the rebase runs fine, what I have run into is that origin/jheigs and local jheigs have HEAD commits that don't match (given the above rebase), so at times I may have to pull and then push, which can cause conflicts. What I am confused about is...should I instead be using:

   ```
   $ git push --force origin jheigs (?)
   ```
2. Second question...now, let's say that I've pushed and jheigs has been rebased correctly with origin/master. No conflicts existed and my jheigs and origin/jheigs are now ahead of master by 1 commit. Ok, a day goes by and I need to make more changes. So I make those changes on jheigs and add/commit. However, origin/master has no additional updates. Essentially I'm still ahead of origin/master by 1 commits (soon to be 2). Do I still follow the same process above? Or do I just add/commit and push to origin/jheigs without rebasing since I'm already ahead of origin/master?

I apologize that this is so length, but I thought I had this figured out and it's just not as smooth as I thought it would be. I want to be careful with rebasing, so any help is appreciated!

Comment: Why are you pulling and then pulling again using rebase? Are you aware what pull does?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, first, I would (and do) just avoid `git pull` entirely, or mostly: it's meant to be convenient, but it turns out to be *in*convenient.  It just runs `git fetch` followed by a second Git command that affects whatever branch you have checked out.  Sometimes I don't want or need the fetch; other times, I want to look around at what happened *when* the fetch ran, *before* I do any second command to affect the current branch.

As you have probably read, `git rebase` is really about *copying* (some) commits.  You have some collection of commits in your repository, and now, for whatever reason, the shine has gone off some commit(s), and you want to make newer, better, prettier, shinier commits.

The way to make all of this make sense is to *draw commit graphs*.  Remember that there are multiple clones—different repositories that contain *mostly* the same sets of commits, but not exactly the same sets—involved!

#### Drawing your own repository's commits

You can have Git do this for you: `git log --all --decorate --oneline --graph`, or git log (with) A DOG.  It's good exercise to do it by hand at first though.  Also, when you do it by hand, you can draw these out horizontally, which tends to make more sense.

Remember that each commit, identified by its unique hash ID, is read-only.  Each commit points back to its *parent* commit.  A branch name like `master` or `jheigs`, or a remote-tracking name like `origin/master` or `origin/jheigs`, *points to* (records the hash ID of) the *tip* commit, and Git works backwards from these tips:

```
...--C--D--E   <-- master
         \
          F--G   <-- jheigs (HEAD)
```

This might be the graph fragment of a repository where commit `E` is the tip of `master`, and `E` points back to `D`, while you've added two commits of your own: `G`, which is the tip of `jheigs` and which points back to `F`, and earlier, you added `F` pointing back to `D`.

Note that here, commits `D` and earlier are on *both* branches.

A `git rebase` will copy<sup>1</sup> some commits to new-and-improved commits.  For instance, here you might want to copy `F` to a new-and-improved `F'`, where the main difference is that `F'` is attached to `E`, not to `D`:

```
             F'   [new and improved!]
            /
...--C--D--E   <-- master
         \
          F--G   <-- jheigs (HEAD)
```

Once you've copied `F` to `F'`, you can now copy `G` to new-and-improved `G'`:

```
             F'-G'   [new and improved!]
            /
...--C--D--E   <-- master
         \
          F--G   <-- jheigs (HEAD)
```

And now that all of the commits that are "on" (reachable from) `jheigs`, but *not* on `master`, have been copied to the new-and-improved version, you can have Git peel the `jheigs` label off commit `G` and paste it onto `G'`:

```
             F'-G'  <-- jheigs (HEAD)
            /
...--C--D--E   <-- master
         \
          F--G   [abandoned]
```

The old, dull `F` and `G` commits that were so shiny and nice yesterday are now junk, replaced with the shiny new `F'` and `G'`.  This is because *your* branch name `jheigs` now points to the last of the new copied commits.

---

<sup>1</sup>This copying is done as if by `git cherry-pick`.  Depending on which rebase command you use, it may actually *be* done with `git cherry-pick`.

---

#### There's another repository involved: `fetch` and `push`

The graph above is for *your* repository, but there's a second repository involved here.  They have their own branch names, and their own commits.  The commits that you have, that they also have, share commit hash IDs.  There might be some commits that you have that they don't; and there might be some commits that they have that you don't.

If you think they might have commits that you don't, you should run `git fetch` or `git fetch origin`.  This has your Git call up their Git, at the URL you have listed under the name `origin`.  Your Git calls up their Git and has them list all of their commits (by hash IDs) as given by *their* branch names.

If they have commits that you don't, your Git now downloads those commits.  Your Git also *changes* their branch names, such as `master` or `jheigs`, so that they read `origin/master` and `origin/jheigs`.  These new names won't interfere with *your* branch names.

Now that you have all the commits that they have, plus all the commits that you had before, your repository perhaps looks like this—let's assume you *haven't* done `git rebase` yet:

```
             H   <-- origin/master
            /
...--C--D--E   <-- master
         \
          F--G   <-- jheigs (HEAD), origin/jheigs
```

Your `origin/*` is your Git's memory of *their* branch names.  This means that *their* `master` identifies commit `H`.  You have commit `H` now, thanks to `git fetch`.  *Their* `jheigs` identifies commit `G`, just like yours.

If you now run `git rebase master`, your Git will copy your `F` and `G` to a new `F'` and `G'`, built to come after commit `E`, which is where your `master` points.  You probably would like to have them come after commit `H` instead.

Here, you can do this pretty easily: you can just run `git rebase origin/master`.  This tells your Git to find commits that you have (i.e., `F` and `G`) that are not *reachable from* your `origin/master` (i.e., their `master`, as far as you can remember anyway) and put the copies after commit `H`.  The result looks like this:

```
               F'-G'  <-- jheigs (HEAD)
              /
             H   <-- origin/master
            /
...--C--D--E   <-- master
         \
          F--G   <-- origin/jheigs
```

Note that none of the `origin/*` names have moved, and your own `master` has not moved either.  However, *their* `jheigs` which you call `origin/jheigs` still remembers commit `G`.

*Now* you need `git push --force jheigs`, to tell them: *Throw away commits `F` and `G` in favor of the new shiny `F'` and `G'`.*  Once they agree to do that, your Git will remember their `jheigs` as pointing to `G'`:

```
               F'-G'  <-- jheigs (HEAD), origin/jheigs
              /
             H   <-- origin/master
            /
...--C--D--E   <-- master
```

With no names to find them, commits `F` and `G` appear to vanish entirely.

#### Why you might not want to rebase, ever

Note that there may be a *third* Git repository out there, and a fourth or more, with another `origin/jheigs` in it.  If so, all those *other* repositories must take some action (such as running `git fetch`) to get the new commits and update their own `origin/jheigs` names.

Further, they might have built their own commits atop your commits before you decided to throw out your commits in favor of new-and-improved ones.  If so, they may be forced to copy *their* commits just like you copied yours.  That might even be a good thing, or it might make them annoyed.

Hence, if you're ever about to rebase commits that *other people* have, or might have, you should be reasonably sure that it's OK to make work for them.  If no one else has the original commits, it's obviously safe to copy-and-replace them.  If everyone else has agreed that this kind of copy-replace is *supposed* to happen, it's still fine.  So rebase if it's OK to do so, and if it makes sense to do so.

Comment: Thanks for such a detailed answer! I really appreciate you taking the time to lay it all out for me. At the company I work at, we're rebasing each of our dev branches to stay up-to-date with master. So, my final question is...in the last commit graph that you laid out `jheigs` and `origin/jheigs` are now ahead of master. What happens if someone comes back to me with a last minute edit to code on `jheigs`? At this point I would add/commit, but I would still be ahead of master, so is a rebase not necessary? Essentially I should just add/commit/push on the `jheigs` branch? Thanks again!

Comment: As long as you are *strictly ahead of* some other branch, the other branch can accommodate your commits by simply "moving forward".  In the examples above, `master` can move forward from `E` to `H` and onward, and `origin/master` can move forward from `H` onward. As long as the other Git's (origin's) `master` really does point to `H`, he'll be able to move his `master` forward. That's a *fast forward* operation, and `git push` lets you know if it's *not* possible, by complaining about *non fast forward*.

Answer (score 0):

> When the rebase runs fine, what I have run into is that origin/jheigs and local jheigs have HEAD commits that don't match (given the above rebase)

Yes, but the difference is your additional un-pushed work. After a `git pull --rebase`, the upstream HEAD will be an *ancestor* of your local HEAD.

> so at times I may have to pull and then push

Which is generally the correct thing to do

> which can cause conflicts.

It shouldn't, unless someone else pushes in between your pull and push (in which case, you need to do it again, to incorporate their work).

> Ok, a day goes by and I need to make more changes. So I make those changes on jheigs and add/commit. However, origin/master has no additional updates. Essentially I'm still ahead of origin/master by 1 commits (soon to be 2). Do I still follow the same process above? Or do I just add/commit and push to origin/jheigs without rebasing since I'm already ahead of origin/master?

Either is fine. If upstream hasn't moved, `git pull --rebase` will do nothing.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I appreciate it! Something I ran into, was that I don't believe upstream moved, but during the rebase I got conflicts with code that I updated locally on `jheigs` (I know because I looked at the conflicts) which hasn't yet been pushed to `master`. It seems like I rebased once yesterday and now when I go to rebase today, it says the changes I already added are now conflicting...I'm sure I'm messing something up, it's just weird. But I can fix the conflicts and move on.